# How do I remove a specific element from local storage array in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my HTML:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="student in students track by $index">
             //some code here
           <button ng-click="remove(student)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

And here's my .js file code for deleting a student(not from local storage):

```
$scope.remove = function(student) {
    var index = $scope.students.indexOf(student);
    $scope.students.splice(index, 1);
}
```

How do I access local storage from my js code and delete a particular student from local storage.

Comment: The only way to delete a localStorage element is by using `localStorage.removeItem("studentKey");` you should loop through them and find the one with the data you want to erase, but if data is repeated it will go wrong... Also you could try just to overwrite it (null) and then validate the field before displaying the data.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I tried adding localStorage.removeItem("studentKey"); to my code but still it won't work, the 'student' argument which I have passed on to that function contains the student object which is to be deleted, is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) the parameter you pass to `localStorage.removeItem("key");` is the field name or element name... if you create `localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");` you delete it like: `localStorage.removeItem("lastname");`... What is the structure of your data?

Comment: Thank you, It worked! I used :
localStorage.setItem('studentsList', JSON.stringify($scope.students));

Just updated with the new $scope.students

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should rephrase your question to be "How do I access browser's local storage from js code?"

You can access [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in your js code with `localStorage`.
I would delete your student from `$scope.students` and when finished, set the new array as an item in local storage:

```
$scope.remove = function(student) {
    var index = $scope.students.indexOf(student);
    $scope.students.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('students', JSON.stringify($scope.students));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I tried your code and added localStorage.setItem('students', $scope.students); to my function, but the items are displayed back after refresh.

Comment: I used localStorage.setItem('studentsList', JSON.stringify($scope.students)); and it worked, thank you.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. I'll update my answer. Additionally, I would advise that you store data in a proper database/data service rather than using browser storage. If you're just messing around with this app for learning/fun then nevermind. But if you want to follow best practice for web apps, I suggest you do that.

Comment: Actually this was an assignment given to me for angularjs and they told me to use anything persistent which can do the job, so I used local storage.